# Why wp_footer() is called in wp_footer() footer.php itself ?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to understand theme creating in WP. And according what I understand wp_footer() includes footer.php in the main page. But what I am don't understand is why wp_footer() is called in footer.php itself like in twentyseventeen footer ?

```
</div><!-- #content -->

        <footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">
            <div class="wrap">
                <?php
                get_template_part( 'template-parts/footer/footer', 'widgets' );

                if ( has_nav_menu( 'social' ) ) : ?>
                    <nav class="social-navigation" role="navigation" aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Footer Social Links Menu', 'twentyseventeen' ); ?>">
                        <?php
                            wp_nav_menu( array(
                                'theme_location' => 'social',
                                'menu_class'     => 'social-links-menu',
                                'depth'          => 1,
                                'link_before'    => '<span class="screen-reader-text">',
                                'link_after'     => '</span>' . twentyseventeen_get_svg( array( 'icon' => 'chain' ) ),
                            ) );
                        ?>
                    </nav><!-- .social-navigation -->
                <?php endif;

                get_template_part( 'template-parts/footer/site', 'info' );
                ?>
            </div><!-- .wrap -->
        </footer><!-- #colophon -->
    </div><!-- .site-content-contain -->
</div><!-- #page -->
<?php wp_footer(); Here?>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

wp_footer() in wordpress in not used for including the footer, in fact get_footer() does that.

The wp_footer() is used for outputting data or doing background actions that run just before closing body tag.

Hope that makes it clear!!

Comment: Exactly. Notice that the other files in the theme that build a page (e.g. `page.php`, `single.php`, `front-page.php` etc) use `get_footer()` which will insert the contents of `footer.php`; `footer.php` itself uses `wp_footer()` for anything else that should be in the footer such as from plugins.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge the wp_footer() in footer.php is used for printing scripts or data before the closing body tag on the front end.

Reference Link: http://www.twoclock.com/wp_footer-wordpress-action-hook/